# How to combine 2 LINQ XML queries in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

noob here using LINQ.
I have created 2 queries that I would like combining if possible.

```
        var myData =
        from el in root.Descendants().Elements("sensor")
        where (string)el.Attribute("name") == "Sensor1"
        select el;

        var myData2 =
        from el in myData.Elements("evt")
        select new
        {
            t1 = el.Attribute("time").Value,
            v1 = el.Attribute("val").Value
        };  

        dataGridView1.DataSource = myData2.ToList();
```

Ideally I'd like to know how to combine the 2 queries.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is posible, you could do this.

```
var result = root.Descendants()
    .Elements("sensor")
    .Where(el=>(string)el.Attribute("name") == "Sensor1")
    .Elements("evt")
    .Select(el=> new
        {
            t1 = el.Attribute("time").Value,
            v1 = el.Attribute("val").Value
        })
     .ToList()
dataGridView1.DataSource = result;
```

Comment: It is called chaining.